# When to use logarithmic variables

Tags: regression

I want to make a regression. My dependent variable Y is a score of discrete numbers from 0 to 12. I have 6 independent variables. Four of them are in percent between 0.4 % and 40 %. The two other independent variables are not in percent. One of them measures years and is between 1.8 and 67. The other independent variable measures size and is between 0.008 and 5,117 (very high).

I don't want to use winsorizing, that's why I decided to use logarithm. My question now: Is it good when I log the two independent variables which are not in percent, because they have high vaules?

That means I would use: reg Y x1 x2 x3 x4 logx5 logx6

Why I would like to use log is because I want to look out for the outliers. I have not really outliers, but I think it's better to use log for comparision reasons.

Or do I just have to use log, when the distribution of some variables is skewed? Meaning log leads to a lower skewness and is thus used appropriately.

Thank you in advance.
Lukas

Comment: `log` skews variables - make small changes near `0` have high impact and huge changes aware from `0` have little impact - [see here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/graphlog.htm). Whether that is something that will help you is a question only you can answer; `y` varies with `a.x` is very different from `y` varies with `log(x)`.

Comment: Anyhow - this would seem to be off topic here. This is a question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), the statistics Stack Exchange.